# Is it ok to initialize a @Component object as a private final property in a data class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it ok to initialize a property as part of a data class like in the code below, when the property is defined as a @Component?

```
@SuperBuilder
@Data
public class DataClass{

    private final RandomUUIDGenerator generator = new RandomUUIDGenerator();

    @Builder.Default
    String uuid = generator.generate();
}
```

The RandomUUIDGenerator is defined like this:

```
@Component
public class RandomUUIDGenerator implements UUIDGenerator {
    public UUID generate() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, however it is not recommended as you are not utilising the benefits of dependency injection. You should autowire RandomUUIDGenerator using @Autowired annotation.

Comment: If I use Autowired I get java.lang.NullPointerException when the object is initialized. It happens because of 
@Builder.Default
    String uuid = generator.generate();